# Multiple files as input to Hadoop Dfs and mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Usually we give in one text file as input to the java file(say in the case of simple word count problem).Instead,now I have 100 csv files which I want to give as input to my java code.(All files can't simply be merged to 1 single file).Trying to predict  max/min stock volatility of the given 100 stocks,hence each csv file is unique.
So,how to give the entire folder of the csv files as the input stream to the java program.

Comment: Mapreduce already accepts folders

Comment: Ideally, you would put the csv into HDFS as is, then you use a Hive or Spark query over it...

Comment: How to make mapreduce accept folder?
Is it by using /* operator?

Comment: Yes, that will work, or you can simply pass the folder name as `arg[0]`, or whatever your code is doing.

Answer (score 2):

Solution 1: For solving this, we can use FileInputFormat.addInputPaths() method, that can take a comma separated list of multiple inputs and we can write it as

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(“file0,file1,....”)
```

or

Suppose 2 files need to be analysed and a list of the people that are using the services of Facebook and youtube (need a single output file out of these)

We have two files facebook.txt and youtube.txt

```
Path YoutubePath = new Path(args[0]);
Path FacebookPath = new Path(args[1]);
Path outputPath = new Path(args[2]);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, FacebookPath, TextInputFormat.class, JoinFacebookMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, YoutubePath, TextInputFormat.class, YoutubeMapper.class);
FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, outputPath);
```

Adding following lines to the code will yield multiple files to be passed within a single map reduce job.

or

You can pass entire folder as argument

Comment: Great example, but is there a way to use multiple input files within MultipleInputs.**AddInputPaths** something like that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is  my test code to copy many files to hdfs and merge them ,it could also filter other file format ,I think  it might be  help to you  !

```
public class FilesMergeToHDFS {
private static FileSystem fs = null;
private static FileSystem local = null;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    list();
}

private static void list() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Configuration conf = new Configuration();   
            URI uri = new URI("hdfs://xxx:9000");//HDFS address
            fs = FileSystem.get(uri,conf);


            local = FileSystem.getLocal(conf);

            FileStatus[] dirsStatus = local.globStatus(new Path("E://data/73/*"), new RegexExcludePathFilter("^.*svn$"));
            Path[] dirs = FileUtil.stat2Paths(dirsStatus);
            FSDataInputStream in = null;
            FSDataOutputStream out = null;
            for(Path p:dirs){
                    //upload
                String filename = p.getName();
                FileStatus[] localStatus = local.globStatus(new Path(p+"/*"),new RegexAcceptPathFilter("^.*txt$"));
                Path[] listedPaths = FileUtil.stat2Paths(localStatus);
                //set outputpath
                Path block = new Path("hdfs://hadoop:9000/mergehdfs/filesmerge/"+filename+".txt");
                out =fs.create(block);
                for(Path path:listedPaths){
                    in = local.open(path);
                    IOUtils.copyBytes(in, out, 4096, false); // copydata
                    in.close();
                }
                if (out != null) {
                    out.close();
                }
            }
}

private static class RegexAcceptPathFilter implements PathFilter {

private final String regex;

    public RegexAcceptPathFilter(String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag = path.toString().matches(regex);
        return flag;
    }

}

private static class RegexExcludePathFilter  implements PathFilter {
private final String regex;
    public RegexExcludePathFilter (String regex) {
        this.regex = regex;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean accept(Path path) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        boolean flag = path.toString().matches(regex);
        return !flag;
    }
}
}
```